# Can a holomorphic function have uncountable many zeros?

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that Weierstrass factorisation theorem holds for point sets in the complex plane without any limit points.

Is there a generalisation of this conclusion if we replace the point set with an uncountable point set in the complex plane without limit points? That is, can a holomorphic function have uncountable many zeros? I believe such a set can be constructed by well-ordering an uncountable point set.

Comment: An uncountable subset of $\mathbb{C}$ **always** has limit points (uncountably many).

Comment: if it isnt the zero function,it could have only countably many since the zeroes are isolated..

Comment: @danielFischer isn't it possible to obtain one by well-ordering an uncountable set? Or where can I find a reference of a proof?

Comment: Well-ordering has nothing to do with it. If a set has no limit point, then it can intersect every compact subset of $\mathbb{C}$ only in finitely many points. Since $\mathbb{C}$ is a countable union of compact subsets, a set without limit points is necessarily (at most) countable.

Comment: I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained in comments by Daniel Fischer, this cannot happen. Here's a slightly more general version, with $\mathbb C$ replaced by an arbitrary domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb C$.

We can write $\Omega$ as the union of a countable family of compact sets $K_n$, for example by letting $K_n=\{z\in \Omega: \operatorname{dist}(z,\partial \Omega) \ge 1/n, \ |z|\le n\}$.

Since the zero set $Z$ has no limit points, each intersection $Z\cap K_n$ is finite. Hence
$$Z = \bigcup_n (Z\cap K_n)$$
is countable.