# Can a smooth function have an uncountable number of roots?

Tags: general-topology, functions

Out of idle curiosity:

Does there exist a smooth but non-constant univariate function $f(x)$ over $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=0$ has an uncountable number of solutions?

My intuition is that the answer is 'no', and that a solid proof of this fact will be simple, but I'm at a loss to think of one. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892864/can-a-holomorphic-function-have-uncountable-many-zeros) about holomorphic functions *seems* pertinent, but it starts with the assumption that no limit points exist, and I'm not sure where this assumption comes from or whether it applies here.

**Edit:** Some answers also concern "Can such a function exist that isn't zero on any interval of $\mathbb{R}$?"

Comment: Do you mean discrete roots or something? Otherwise just take $f$ to be identically $0$...or $0$ for $x≤0$ and $\exp(-\frac 1{x^2})$ for $x>0$.

Comment: @lulu: I think that's why the "non-constant" provision.

Comment: The standard non-analytic smooth function on $\mathbb R$ is zero for $x\leq 0$ and non-zero for $x>0$:$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&x>0\\0&x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

Comment: @EliRose  My second example is non-constant.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews - I wasn't aware of its existence. This was the kind of example I was looking for. Thanks. Also, lulu.

Comment: If you want it to be non-constant on any interval, that is likely to be impossible.

Comment: @lulu: Ah, it is! my apologies.

Comment: Moreover, it can be shown that any uncountable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is dense in some interval (think about it), and if a continuous function is $0$ on a set dense in $[a, b]$, then it's identically $0$ on the interval.

Comment: @AJY: this is false, consider the Cantor set, which is nowhere dense.

Comment: Dang. It is not my morning. Don't know why I didn't think of that one.

Comment: @AJY: But you can say that any uncountable subset of $\mathbb R$ is locally uncountable at some point, meaning that there exists $x \in \mathbb R$ such that every open interval containing $x$ contains uncountably many points of the set. In fact, the set is locally uncountable at one of that set's points. In fact, the set is locally uncountable at all but countably many of that set's points. (Cantor-Bendixson theorem)

Comment: Yes. I was thinking about it and knew you could find an interval where every neighborhood had uncountable intersection, but hadn't figured where to get density (for reasons now obvious).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard non-analytic smooth function on $\mathbb R$ is zero for $x\leq 0$ and non-zero for $x>0$:$$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-1/x^2}&x>0\\0&x\leq 0\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 7):

Every closed subset of $\mathbb R$ is the precise zero set of a $C^\infty$ function. That includes closed intervals, a convergent sequence, a Cantor set, ...

Comment: Do you have a reference? Or an example? In particular for the Cantor set?

Comment: @Loic  Again, it's any closed set; there's nothing particularly hard about the Cantor set. There should be a proof here at MSE or some other website.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Just take any smooth function with compact support. The set where it is zero is $\mathbb{R}$ minus a compact set, which is uncountable.

I think you wanted to formulate the question differently, though.