# $f$ entire and non-constant function, then for fix $x \in \mathbb{C}$ the set of $(z \in \mathbb{C} : f(z)=x)$ is finite or countable.

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, complex-numbers

If $f$ entire and non-constant function, then for fix $x \in \mathbb{C}$ the set of $(z \in \mathbb{C} : f(z)=x)$ is finite or countable.

I was trying to prove this statement by contradiction or using the continuity of $f$ but unsuccessfully.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1334557/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/892864/42969.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it was uncountable, then it would admit an accumulation point. However, then $f$ was constant by the identity theorem.

Comment: How do we know that there is an accumulation point? I assume it has something to do with Bolzano-Weierstrass or Compactness but we don´t know if the uncountable set is bounded or closed, or? Or it has something to do with a continuity?

Comment: the complex plane is the union of countable closed balls (take radius $n$) so given uncountable many points in the plane, it follows an uncountable subset of them are in at least one closed ball

Comment: This is a standard fact. I like to see it the following way: If your set is uncountable, then there exists an interval $[-R;R]$ which intersects our uncountable set in uncountably many points (write $\mathbb{R}=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} [-n;n]$). Then you play the same game bisecting the interval in half, always keeping the half which intersects the uncountable set in uncountably many points. Then take the intersection of all those smaller and smaller intervals (which gives you a point), and note that this is an accumulation point of your uncountable set.

Comment: Yeah, but here we are talking about complex numbers and not real numbers, does that change anything?

Comment: Nope, not at all. Then we do it with squares instead.